# Bootstrap 4 flexbox error

Tags: css, frameworks, alignment, flexbox, navbar

, I'm triying to use the flexbox options in the recent version of bootstrap 4...and I want to set some spaces on my nav elements...this, using the flexbox classes made by bootstrap...here is the navbar example show on bootstrap documentation I just added the classes I need to the end of nav element but nothing happens...the brand element and the list are not moving at all...HELP PLS !

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light d-flex justify-content-end flex-row ">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand align-self-start" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                          <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Portada
                                      </a>
                                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                      </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Soluciones
                                      </a>
                                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                      </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clientes</a>
                                </li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
              </nav>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It would help if you provide a working demo, too. I made one for you here. Seems OK to me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgpwLM

Comment: @MichaelCoker take a look of the justify-content-end class ...it should move all the elements at the end of navbar space...if I set the justify-content-center---it should center them

Comment: Are you trying to align everything in the nav to the right? If so, you can use `#navbarNav {
  width:auto;
}` and the `justify-content: flex-end;` rule will align things to the end of the nav.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I'm sure this could be the solution....but I'm using the bootstrap class designed for flexbox...take a look of this

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: The problem is that `#navbarNav.navbar-collapse` is a direct descendent of `nav.d-flex.navbar-toggleable-md` and `.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-collapse` has `width: 100%;` in bootstrap CSS. That means `#navbarNav` takes up all of the available space under `nav`, meaning nothing can be aligned to the right since there is no available space to move anything since `#navbarNav` aligns everything to the right. If you disable `width: 100%` on #navbarNav, then it and the other flex children can align right as you want them to.

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeah !! it's working now !! ty!!...pls add your post as answer....I have other question...If I disable the 100% width of the element you mention....responsivity of the nav will be affected right ?

Comment: The behavior of the navbar seems the same whether `width: auto;` is assigned or not. Try it out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpKQXB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `justify-content: flex-end;` doesn't work currently is because `#navbarNav` is `width: 100%;` which means it is taking up all of the available space in `nav.navbar`, leaving no room to shift the children of `nav.navbar` to the flex-start or flex-end. One way you can get `nav.navbar` to align it's flex-items to `flex-end` is assign `width: auto;` to `#navbarNav`, which will free up space to shift the children of `nav.navbar` to the flex-start or flex-end.

```css
#navbarNav {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light d-flex justify-content-end flex-row ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand align-self-start" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Portada
                                      </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nosotros</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Soluciones
                                      </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nosotros</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Clientes</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```